# How to prepare automatic text labelling for legend using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, cartography, layouts

I need to label for text with legend without ungrouping layers.  I have attached an example image to show the expected output model.

I am looking for your guidance.

[image]

Comment: Are the number of cases or names of the cases subject to change?

Comment: @artwork, I need names short forms within the box.

Comment: Yes I understand that, right now you are showing 4 different cases. May the number of cases increase or decrease in the future (e.g. 3 cases or 7 cases)?

Comment: Yes may it will increase in future. Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Are the short forms within the box only present in the legend or are they visible in the map too?

Comment: I expect both map and legend.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your map to show how these features appear?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it isn't simple.

1. Add Descriptions to your legend items (here are [instructions](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17447)).  In your case, you'll want the description to be your short text (like MT).
2. In your symbology tab, change your items so the Label is your long text (like Mixed tree crop).
3. Add your legend.  Go to the Items tab and right-click on your Legend item to open the Legend Item Properties window.  Click Properties and go to the Arrangement tab.  Choose the fourth one down- symbol patch, Description, Label.
4. While still in the Legend Item Properties window, click the General tab and make sure that "Show Descriptions" and "Show Labels" are checked.
5. While still in the Legend Item Properties window, click the "Description Symbol" button.  Click the "Edit Symbol" button.  Go to the Advanced Text tab and click the box next to "Text Background".  You'll want to go into that Properties menu and make the text background match your symbol (your orange square).  Note- it defaults to a balloon callout.  You probably want to change the Type drop-down menu to "Marker Text Background" and then find a square marker.
6. Go back to the Legend Item Properties Window.  Still on the General tab, check the box next to "Override default patch size" and set the Width and Height both to zero.

You should see the legend just like your picture, but it is a painful method.  You have to have your data really broken up- it wouldn't work if you have a layer with several symbols because you only get one description symbol for the whole layer.  So, you'll need your MT, MV, Ru, and RS as individual layers in your TOC.